# Mapbox marker with multiple titles

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, leaflet, mapbox

At some locations (coordinates) multiple points exist and I want the titles to be combined in the tooltip.

Here's the jbuilder file

```
json.type "FeatureCollection"
json.features @years do |year|
  json.type "Feature"
  json.properties do
    if (year.resto)
      json.set! "marker-color", "#9932CC"
      json.set! "marker-symbol", "restaurant"
    else
      json.set! "marker-color", "#5cb85c"
      json.set! "marker-symbol", "lodging"
    end

    json.set! "marker-size", "small"
    json.title "#{year.person.given_name} #{year.person.last_name} was a #{year.title} at #{year.location.address} on #{year.year_date}" 
  end
  if (year.location.longitude) 
    json.geometry do
      json.type "Point"
      json.coordinates [year.location.longitude, year.location.latitude]
    end
  end
end
```

At some coordinates several items may exist. Only one shows up. I tried MarkerClusterGroup and all the items show up, but would rather have the titles just stacked in one tooltip. Any hints on how to go about this? Thank you

The js file

```
function makeMap() {
  L.mapbox.accessToken = $('body').data('mapboxToken');
  var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
             .setView([34.040951, -118.258579], 13);

  var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
                    .loadURL('map/map_data.geojson')
                    .addTo(map);

  featureLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(featureLayer.getBounds());
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but I think I can test in jbuilder and build up the Title.

Started to think this through and it wouldn't be straightforward. Might require database to be modified which if it works out is OK.

Easier if Mapbox/Leaflet could handle it.